# Building Android for x86_64 using delphi

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-12-athens

I have several target options in Delphi, but I seem to be missing a Target for Android targeting the "x86_64" binary for my "library.so" file.

I can't add a new Target, and I wondered if someone knows how to build a .so for x86_64 using Delphi 12.

My Android simulator is running on a 64-bit Intel processor:
[image]

When I try and run my tests or test UI code, I get an error, it seems logical to me as the underlying operating system is Windows and the platform is Intel and not ARM

When I click debug, I get the following:

Is it possible to compile for X86_64 so I can integrate my library in .net as shown here:
https://github.com/xtuzy/Veldrid.SPIRV.NativeAsset/tree/master/Veldrid.SPIRV.AndroidNativeAsset

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think all of the Android compilers of Delphi target arm. For x86_64 there are compilers for Windows and Linux.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it will be Intel when you execute a simulator in Windows. If I call my ARM-based Delphi assembly using MAUI on Windows, the application terminates.

Comment: I don't understand this, and judging by the engagement on this question I am not alone. I think you may need to do more with the question.